# What CSS properties are likely to cause problems in Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I designed a web page with lot of CSS properties, and when viewing it in IE its alignment is not so proper compared to all other browsers.

For the next time, what are the CSS properties I should take care with in IE?

Thank you.

Comment: *All* of them, seriously.

Comment: I mean some properties like margins and paddings ..

Comment: Depends on the version of IE you are using, read up on box models and the way IE handles things slightly differently for a start.

Comment: IE is a nightmare for web designers

Comment: Voting to close, this is *waaaaay* too broad a question. IE is incredibly broken in detail.

Comment: you should ask what properties work in IE, it has only one: `web-browser: doubtful`. Though IE 9 looks somewhat better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `div` with a margin floated to the same side, it will cause a double margin in IE:

```
div
{
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

or

```
div
{
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

The margin will in fact be 20px in IE.

The fix is to add `display:inline`.

Comment: display:inline is a bit awkward for a fix, I'd recommend using padding where possible or halving the margin in an IE6 specific rule instead.

Answer (score 1):

[Very](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) [nearly](http://positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) [everything](http://css-class.com/test/bugs/ie/ie-bugs.htm) [breaks](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200612/internet_explorer_and_the_css_box_model/) [IE](http://css-tricks.com/ie-css-bugs-thatll-get-you-every-time/).

Comment: And http://haslayout.net/css/index - this one was in a different bookmark folder :)

Comment: Funnily enough they have the more logical box model.

Comment: @Keyo - well that's kind of subjective but you're not the onyl one who thinks so. I wouldn't credit the IE team for this though - the rest of IE suggests it's a happy(?) accident :)

Comment: I blame W3C for being retarded on this one more than anything else. :/

Answer (score 1):

First thing to say is that you should make sure your HTML code always has a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration. This will force it into "standards mode", which makes IE much more consistent with other browsers. (it's still got tons of missing and broken features, but its nothing compared to the disaster you'll get without a doctype).

For finding out what those missing and broken features are, I recommend you take a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html.

The Quirksmode site has an excellent set of tables showing exactly which CSS properties and other functionality work in which browsers. It also has details of exactly what the bugs are in specific cases. If I ever have a question like this, Quirksmode is the first place I go to find the answer.

The second place I go to find the answer is http://caniuse.com/. However this site focusses more on newer features, so may not tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Stay clear of using the following, it doesnt play nice in ie.

```
display:inline-block
```

Comment: It actually works for me. Not everywhere, but it's a known trick to fix some weird behavior without actually meaning to get an inline-block. The ways of IE are dark...

Comment: aye , using zoom:1 helps, but its far from useable, in my opinion